# How to get many rows based on several uniqueidentifiers?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to make a select like this:

```
DECLARE @ContentIDs VARCHAR(MAX);

SELECT @ContentIDs = 'e28faa48-adea-484d-9d64-ba1e1c67eea3,8338A6DE-8CDF-4F52-99CE-62E2B107FF97'

SELECT * FROM [Content] WHERE [ID] IN (@ContentIDs)
```

It only returns the content with the first `UNIQUEIDENTIFIER`.

How can I retrieve all rows?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could

1. use dynamic SQL to generate the query but would need to be sure the list was sanitised
2. use a split function to parse the list and add each entry as a row into a table variable which you then join on that or
3. use `SELECT * FROM [Content] WHERE @ContentIDs like '%' + cast([ID] as varchar(36)) + '%'` this will force a full scan but if you are matching many rows this might not matter. (**Edit** but if you are matching many rows the comparison string will likely be huge!)

Option 2 would generally be my preferred approach. Or you could use a CTE to do something similar (Based on [approach here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/transactsql/thread/6ab63d2f-5eff-4084-ac12-f4fb4a0e23c6))

```
DECLARE @ContentIDs VARCHAR(MAX);

SET @ContentIDs = 'e28faa48-adea-484d-9d64-ba1e1c67eea3,8338A6DE-8CDF-4F52-99CE-62E2B107FF97';

WITH Guids(pn, start, [stop]) AS
(
      SELECT 1, cast(1 as bigint), CHARINDEX(',', @ContentIDs)
      UNION ALL
      SELECT pn + 1, [stop] + 1, CHARINDEX(',', @ContentIDs, [stop] + 1)
      FROM Guids
      WHERE [stop] > 0
)

SELECT <collist> FROM 
[Content] 
WHERE [ID] IN (
    SELECT 
    CAST(LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(@ContentIDs, start, 
       CASE WHEN [stop] > 0 
            THEN [stop]-start 
            ELSE LEN(@ContentIDs) END))) AS UNIQUEIDENTIFIER)
    FROM Guids where  [stop] > 0 or start>1
    )
```

Comment: Since in this case I won't have more than 15 IDs I guess I can use option 3, its pretty simple. Options 2 sounds the perfect solution though, I might try it sometime.

Answer (score 3):

That is because "IN" expects a table and you're giving it a string. Even with the "like" as suggested it would be very sloppy and your results won't be accurate at all.

You'd need something like the following to convert the string to a table for it to work:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[split] (

    @sourcestring varchar(8000),
    @spliton varchar(1)
)

RETURNS @split table(value sql_variant)

AS  
BEGIN 

    while (charindex(@spliton,@sourcestring)>0)
        begin
            insert into @split
            select value = ltrim(rtrim(substring(@sourcestring,1,charindex(@spliton,@sourcestring)-1)))

            set @sourcestring = substring(@sourcestring,charindex(@spliton,@sourcestring) + len(@spliton),len(@sourcestring))
        end
    insert into @split select value = ltrim(rtrim(@sourcestring))

    RETURN

END
```

And then call it like this:

```
DECLARE @ContentIDs VARCHAR(MAX);

SELECT @ContentIDs = 'e28faa48-adea-484d-9d64-ba1e1c67eea3,8338A6DE-8CDF-4F52-99CE-62E2B107FF97'

SELECT * FROM [Content] WHERE [ID] IN (select value from dbo.split(@ContentIDs,','))
```

Comment: just an added note, with sql 2005/2008, you can declare @sourcestring with varchar(MAX) to allow for longer strings than just 8000 characters.

Comment: The results would be perfectly accurate. All Guids are the same length and can't contain commas.

Comment: true, but let me explain why (hopefully giving you the idea of how I approached and solved this problem a few years back)

if "12345" = "12345,67890,123456789" then
'Do something
end if

Above will never fire. Because what the OP is doing is comparing a field "12345" with a string containing more than one option. There is no way for a LIKE to determine or break up the string in several portions for it to be able to give back any valid data in my opinion.

The solution I provided is being used in production with over 10 million rows of data in a single table (and many more tables)

Comment: @AcidRaZor I agree that the split approach will likely be much better but only on performance grounds not accuracy in this particular case.

Comment: How would it not be accurate? Since I've been doing this (I think the code was written pre-2005 even) I haven't had a complaint of inaccuracy when dealing with the auditors.

Comment: @AcidRaZor - That isn't what I said.

Answer (score 1):

You can do a string comparision with the comma-separated list:

```
SELECT * 
FROM [Content] 
WHERE ',' + @ContentIDs + ',' LIKE '%,' + CONVERT(varchar, [ID]) + ',%'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
SELECT @SQL = 'SELECT * FROM [Content] WHERE [ID] IN (' + @ContentIDs + ')'
EXEC (@SQL)
```